# PHP redirect a 503 without URL change

Tags: php, redirect, error-handling, http-headers

what I do is some URL parsing at the very top of my picture page, before outputting anything:

```
foobar.com/pictures.php/2134613514/nice-sunset
```

If that goes wrong for any reason, I want to send the user to my error page.

For 404, 403 etc. I redirect to that same page using .htaccess, which is easy:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 402 /error.php?e=402
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
```

So what I do in pictures.php is:

```
try
{
    // parse PATH_INFO, grab image from db, ...
}
catch (Exception $e) // if that goes wrong for any reason
{
    whack_error_to_log( $e );
    header("Location: /error.php?e=503");
    exit();
}
```

What buggers me is, that the user will see **foobar.com/error.php?e=503** as the url, I would rather like him to see **foobar.com/pictures/2134613514/nice-sunset**, because ideally that URL will come back up, once I found the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
try
{
    // parse PATH_INFO, grab image from db, ...
}
catch (Exception $e) // if that goes wrong for any reason
{
    whack_error_to_log( $e );
    $_GET['e'] = 503;
    include 'error.php';
    exit();
}
```

its a hack, but it should work

Comment: It works. Perfect. Thank you!
(and all else I looked up in the meantime doesn't btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Include the script file instead of redirecting to it:

```
whack_error_to_log( $e );
$_GET['e'] = '503';
include 'error.php';
exit();
```